# A curious trigonometric equality

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, trigonometry, complex-numbers, multivalued-functions

Let's consider the following expression:

$(1)\cos(15\sqrt{2}^\circ) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt[\sqrt{2}]{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}} +  \frac{1}{2}\sqrt[\sqrt{2}]{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}$

The left hand side of the equality represents only one value. On the other hand, the right hand side represents an infinitely number of periodic values, one of which is $\cos(15\sqrt{2}^\circ)$. But not only the cosine of this irrational angle is a value of the right hand side, but also is the principal value.

In fact, you can check that both expressions are numerically equal when evaluated in Wolfram Alpha.

The value of the lect-hand side is here

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos+%282%5E1%2F2pi%2F12%29&x=0&y=0

And the value of the right hand side of $(1)$

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%283%5E1%2F2%2F2%2Bi%2F2%29%5E%281%2F2%5E%281%2F2%29%29%2B1%2F2%283%5E1%2F2%2F2-i%2F2%29%5E%281%2F2%5E%281%2F2%29%29&x=0&y=0

The question is: Is correct the use of the equality sign between a single-valued function and a multiple-valued one, by the convention that the multi-valued function takes his principal value? is there any objection to the equality $(1)$ or is it correct by the convention of the principal value?

Comment: First, it's expressions, not functions. I would say it's OK, as long as you either somehow specify which of multiple values you mean or at least express that it's one of them (rather than all).

Comment: The question on notation is perhaps a good one.  However, the identity is not that curious.  It is just the standard identity $\cos \theta = (e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})/2$ for the value $\theta = \sqrt{2}\pi/12$.

Comment: Also you need to be careful when combining multi-value expressions: you may need to be clear how the values are paired up. A good example is a cubic equation with real coefficients and 3 real solutions (rather than 1 real and 2 complex): the solution is expressed as a sum of cubic roots of two conjugate complex numbers. A complex number has 3 cubic roots, but you need to pair them up as 3 conjugate pairs (rather than using all 9 combinations).